# cannot pass arguments in a signal/slot/connect routine

Tags: c++, qt, signals, connect, slot

I want to do something pretty simple. Click on a toggle-button and get a message-box in QT.

cpp:

```
_show_hide_password = new QPushButton( "abc" );
_show_hide_password->setCheckable( true );
...
QMessageBox* show_password_warning = new QMessageBox ( this );
...
connect( _show_hide_password, SIGNAL ( toggled( bool ) ), this, SLOT ( showHidePw_ButtonAction( QMessageBox* show_password_warning ) ) );


void showHidePw_ButtonAction( QMessageBox* dialog ){...}
```

h:

```
public slots:
  void showHidePw_ButtonAction( QMessageBox* dialog);
```

No matter how I format the SLOT in the connect or in the .h, I cannot parse an argument to the slot. This is pretty annoying. However, it works when I do not pass arguments to the slot at all:

cpp:

```
connect( _show_hide_password, SIGNAL ( toggled( bool ) ), this, SLOT ( showHidePw_ButtonAction() ) );
```

h:

```
public slots:
  void showHidePw_ButtonAction( );
```

But I am not allowed to keep the QMessageBox* show_password_warning global in the .h-data.

How to get pass an argument the function declared in the signal?

I suppose that this is a pretty simple use-case. There should be a nice and clean solution which does not require some over-the-top blew up the code signal transforming functions.

It compiles without problem, but I get the following error after starting the program:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot PinEntryDialog::showHidePw_ButtonAction( QMessageBox* show_password_warning ) in pinentrydialog.cpp:198
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only parameters a slot should have are the same parameters as the signal.

You have two options, both of which are fairly straightforward:

1. Make `show_password_warning` a member variable of your class
2. Create `show_password_warning` inside the `showHidePw_ButtonAction()` method and delete it when you're done with it.